# Finding source IP address in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find source IP address of the received packet using python 3, but without success. Does anyone has an idea how to do that? I want to reply to multicast message with unicast message to the sender and also make a list of senders IP addresses.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to sniff a packet? or is the packet already captured by python?   if you want to sniff the packet, read the information, create a new packet and send it to the sender, you can use [scapy](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)